# （ものか）そんなばかなことがあるものか — such a stupid thing or not stupid at all?

Tags: expressions, rhetorical-questions

The full sentence is:

> 会社が業績不振で給料が30％カットされるなんて、そんなばかなことがあるものか.

Does it mean "such a stupid thing" or "not a stupid thing at all"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「会社{かいしゃ}が業績不振{ぎょうせきふしん}で給料{きゅうりょう}が30％カットされるなんて、**そんなばかなこと**があるものか。」
>
> Does it mean "such a stupid thing" or "not a stupid thing at all"?

The former - "such a stupid thing".

「あるものか」 means "**there should never be** (such a stupid thing)".  In other words, 「あるものか」 is a negative expression that is synonymous to 「あるはずがない」、「あってはならない」, etc.

> "There should never be such a stupid thing as getting 30% of our salaries cut down because of the poor business performance of our company."